# why is this function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an exercise right now, and I can't figure out why this is returning undefined.

```
function every(array, compare) {
    var newArray = array.filter(
        function(property) {
            return compare(property);
        }
    );

    if (newArray === undefined || newArray.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}


console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

as you can see, I'm supposed to get true and false but instead I get undefined and undefined. Why is this the case? I think it's because I'm not understanding isNaN properly but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What happens if the `if` doesn't run? A function returns `undefined` by default...

Comment: `I'm supposed to get true and false` - when does your function return `true`?

Comment: Note that the `return` inside the `filter` does not return from the `every` function, it just determines the filter result (for a single array element).

Comment: `return array.filter(compare).length`

Comment: You should not use `filter` to implement `every`. Use a plain loop. If you want to use builtin methods, go for `every`, and if you don't want to spoil the fun implement it using `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isNaN` return true when it's argument is `NaN`, that means that your filter function keeps `NaN`'s but removes everything else. Its length is only `0` if the array had no NaN's in it. For such an array your function returns false:

```
console.log(every([4], isNaN)); // false
```

That seems to be the opposite of what you want. You called your function `every` but it acts more like it should be called `some`.

For everything else it returns `undefined` (instead of `true`) because you don't have a return statement in any other case. Your only return statement is inside the if statement, so if the condition isn't truthy it returns `undefined`. One way to fix it is to change it so that it returns the result of the comparison `newArray.length === array.length`:

```
function every (array, compare){
    var newArray = array.filter(
        function (property){
            return compare(property);  
        }
    );

    return newArray.length === array.length;

}


console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

The alternative is to negate the return value of `compare` inside your filter callback (See @Shomz's answer) and then `return newArray.length === 0;`.

Comment: Didn't see your answer when I started writing mine. This is all that's needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (newArray === undefined || newArray.length == 0)
    return false;
```

This will trigger only if your new array is empty or undefined. Otherwise the function returns `undefined`. Fix that and also reverse the return of your callback function because `isNaN` is true when a value is not a number.

See here:

```js
function every(array, compare) {
  var newArray = array.filter(
    function(property) {
      return !compare(property);
    }
  );
  return newArray.length == 0;
}


console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

Comment: Note that `newArray === undefined` is not possible, since [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) never returns `undefined`. The condition may as well just be shortened to `newArray.length === 0`.

Comment: @Paulpro, that's true, thank you. Basically, OP just needs to change the return statement. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JeffBurghess You're welcome, I'm glad to help! Though I think Paulpro's answer is better.

Comment: ah that's actually true. I didn't even realize there were other answers